# CSS - items not staying inline within div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 2 items to display inline-block within a div but nothing I've tried is working.

The html I've used is

```
 <div class="quotation">
     <ul>  
      <li><img src="images/quotes.png" alt="" class="quotemarks"></li>
      <li><p class="words">All honour to the Enderbies, therefore, whose house, I think, exists to the present day; though doubtless the original Samuel must long ago have slipped his cable for the great South Sea of the other world.</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Whilst my CSS at the moment is as follows:

```
.quotation {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20% 5% 10% 5%;
  width: 88.2%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #bdc3c7; 
}

.quotation ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.quotemarks {
  max-width: 20%;
}

.words {
  width: 60%;
}
```

I cannot understand why .quotemarks and .words won't a) stay within .quotation and b) won't render inline.

Comment: a) They don't stay in `div.quotation` because you assigned a `max-height` to that, and the content is higher. b) `p ` by default has `display: block;` and you never told it to be anything other than that.

Answer (score 5):

You have quite some things wrong in your code and understanding of how css layout works.

1. You tell your list items to be `display: inline-block`. This tells them to be *just as wide as their content*.
2. You tell the content of your list items - the img and the paragraph - to have their width based on % - *which refers to % of the width of the parent element* - which happens to be the list item.

**So basically the list item asks its content "How wide am I needed to be?" - while the content asks the parent list item "How wide are you? I'll be xy % of that."**

It's easy to see that each element *needs* an answer before it can *give* one, creating an infinite loop of unanswered questions.

Apart from that, as soon as there is any whitespace (even a linebreak only) between two or more inline-block elements whose summed up width is 100% will make (at least) the last element wrap to a new line.

How to solve the `inline-block` whitespace issue: Either make your list-items `float: left;` (which has its own pitfalls!) or set `font-size: 0;` on the parent element (in this case the `ul`) , and re-set it on children as needed.

Also, put the width-controlling classes on the list items.

```css
.quotation {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20% 5% 10% 5%;
  width: 88.2%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
.quotation ul {
  /*set this to avoid linebreak due to whitespace */
  font-size: 0;
}
.quotation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  /* re-set font-size here to what you need */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.quotemarks {
  max-width: 20%;
}
.words {
  width: 60%;
}
.quotemarks img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotation">
  <ul>
    <li class="quotemarks">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="words">
      <p>All honour to the Enderbies, therefore, whose house, I think, exists to the present day; though doubtless the original Samuel must long ago have slipped his cable for the great South Sea of the other world.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Connexo, yeah I know I've still got a lot to learn - I've sort of ended up trying to shoehorn everything I could think of to get this working. It's for a code-test for a (junior) job too. Might not be getting it this time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Move your classes .quotemark and words to parent elements

```
<div class="quotation">
    <ul>  
        <li class="quotemarks"><img src="images/quotes.png" alt=""></li>
        <li class="words"><p>All honour to the Enderbies, therefore, whose house, I think, exists to the present day; though doubtless the original Samuel must long ago have slipped his cable for the great South Sea of the other world.</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Make sure that you added necessary vertical-align rule (top, middle or bottom... ) to your list items.

Check out [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zahorodnyk/mumjrg2h/1/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's a great help, they both display inline now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your solutions worked and, whilst my CSS is still ugly as sin, everything fits in the box and I was able to change the size of the quotemarks too.

```
<div class="quotation">
        <ul>  
          <li class="quotemarks"><img src="images/quotes.png" alt=""></li>
          <li class="words"><p>All honour to the Enderbies, therefore, whose house, I think, exists to the present day</p></li>
       </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.quotation {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20% 5% 200px 5%;
  width: 88.2%;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #bdc3c7; 
}

.quotation ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.quotemarks {
  max-width: 20%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

 .quotemarks img {
    height: 40px;
  }

.words {
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This ***only accidentally*** works and will break as soon as the list item containing the img reaches your allowed max-width of 20%.

Comment: Ah well, small victories - I'll take accidentally working for the moment :-) That said, why would it break if that's all the li will contain? Cheers for your help anyway.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate all your help with this.